# Cookie read correctly in controllers but not in middleware - Laravel

Tags: laravel, cookies, middleware

I was trying to set a cookie to define a user-preferred language. I did that by having a link that leads to a helper controller :

> /set-locale/{locale}

```
public function edit_locale($locale) {
    $durata= 2628000; // "forever"

    if (Cookie::has('locale')) {
        Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('locale')); // If locale cookie is already defined, delete it
    }

    Cookie::queue("locale", $locale, $durata); // Set the cookie to either "en", "fr" or "ar"

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I know this works correctly because if I do :

```
dd(Cookie::get('locale'));
```

It shows the correct locale chosen. So next step was to actually apply this chosen locale everywhere using a middleware, I named it "SetLocale" :

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Cookie::has('locale')) {
        $locale = Cookie::get('locale'); // The cookie gotten here is all scrambled for some reason
    } else {
        // other logic for when cookie is not set (irrelevant for this question)
    }

    App::setLocale($locale);

    return $next($request);
}
```

But if I execute

```
dd(Cookie::get('locale'));
```

here in the middleware, it reads the cookie all scrambled.
So my question is why is it doing that and how do I read the cookie correctly from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, esmaill's answer didn't work for me (Got a "unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 43 bytes" error) but it did help point me in the right direction to solve it.

All I did was add 'locale' to the $except attribute of the EncryptCookies middleware and reset the cookie and now it's read correctly.

Answer (score 1):

use this to get cookie from request :

```
\Crypt::decrypt(Cookie::get('locale'))
```

or use

```
\Crypt::decryptString(Cookie::get('locale'))
```